# Facebook subscribe to real-time updates on a public page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been reading a lot about Facebook Page Real-time updates (RTUs), but the more I read the more confused I get, there are so many contradictory articles on this, and the Facebook documentation, is really high level.

So can someone verify my understanding?
Can I subscribe to any Facebook public page for RTUs?
How does it all link together. Apps, pages and subscriptions?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only subscribe to RTU for pages you manage, not for public pages.

Here's an article that describes the basic flow:

https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2014/12/11/real-time-updates-for-page-conversions/

For available page object subscriptions see the docs here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.4

Comment: I am able to query public pages for their feed data, but yet I cannot setup a RTU to a public page? This seems wrong to me.

Comment: I followed the instructions in the first article to get my app to subscribe to feed and conversations, but how do I hook this up to a specific facebook page? My app has 2 public pages, but after this subscription and verification, I still do not get any posts to my end point if I comment or reply on my page. My Get method was successful, and it says its active, but still no posts. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not wrong. Imagine everyone could subscribe to multiple pages of his choice and get updates whenever a check-in occurs. It's meant for developers and page owners, not as RSS feed.

Comment: You need both sides to make them work:

App subscriptions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/app/subscriptions

Page subscribed apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lars. Regards the Page subscribed apps, do you have an example of hooking this up, I am unclear on how to do it, even after reading the page you provided.                                             It says "You can make a POST request to subscribed_apps edge from the following paths:
/{page_id}/subscribed_apps
When posting to this edge, no Graph object will be created."              Can I do it via postman, or the grph api, or even just via url? Is this something you have done? An example would be brilliant.

Comment: To subscribe an app to a page, use https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID/subscriptions?access_token=PAGEACCESSTOKEN